# Buddhism and homosexuality

Tags: life

Is Buddhism accepting homosexuality? It is a famous question now.I want to know "Is lord Buddha accede homosexuality?[image]

Comment: See also [How is sexual misconduct explained in regards to the five precepts?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/1371/254)

Comment: This thread also discusses homosexuality: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1886/what-is-the-attitude-toward-homosexuality-in-buddhism?noredirect=1&lq=1"></a>