# Is shame and remorse unskillful?

Tags: personal-practice, mind-states

I read this [in another answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3949/254) on this site:

> "and later I regretted" -- remorse is a klesha, an obscuring emotion.

my person thought it's worthy to lift the question if shame and remorse (before, while and after a deed be mind, speech or body) are generally unskillful, therefore to be abandoned, or if certain shame and remorse is actually skillful and very needed, therefore to develop and relay on it.

(Note that remorse/*kukkucca*, as a hindrance, falls by abounding sense-desire, end of reason for ill-will)

Feel invited to reflect, and possible share even Buddhas view on this mind qualities: An invitation of shameless making merits, so that one might not feel remorse, having not done, later.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma, not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gain by means of trade and exchange]*

Comment: In a now-deleted comment, you quoted MN 61, "If, on reflection, you know that it led to self-affliction, to the affliction of others, or to both; it was an unskillful mental action with painful consequences, painful results, then you should feel distressed, ashamed, & disgusted with it.".

Answer (score 3):

The [other answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3949/254) on this site was fine in its essence, spirit, purpose & intent.

There is the unwholesome 'remorse' or 'guilt' ([*kukkucca*](https://suttacentral.net/define/kukkucca)), which is a hindrance; and there is the wholesome 'sense of shame' ([*hiri*)](https://suttacentral.net/define/hiri), which is a virtue and one of the five gates to Dhamma.

As the [other answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3949/254) on this site implied shame towards unskilful deeds is for a Buddha a means of learning a lesson and moving beyond guilt & remorse.

The Lord Buddha said:

> He who having been heedless is heedless no more, illuminates this world like the moon freed from clouds.
>
> He, who by good deeds covers the evil he has done, illuminates this world like the moon freed from clouds.
>
> For it is a cause of growth in the Dhamma & Discipline of the noble
>   ones when, seeing a transgression as such, one makes amends in
>   accordance with the Dhamma and exercises restraint in the future.

Comment: The last verse is one of your little jokes, isn't it. I kind of wish you wouldn't do that because IMO it risks misleading people.

Comment: :) You are always welcome to moderate & edit any of my posts. There is no need to ask. Thank you again Chris for your service, here. With metta

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's part of a skillful response to unskillful action.

Conversely, "shameless" is usually portrayed as undesirable.

The response to skillful virtue is said to be "lack of remorse".

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes yes, sometimes no. It depends on the circumstances.

Sometimes shame and remorse can guide you to do skillful actions.

Sometimes it can guide you to do unskillful actions.