# What is meant by "those crowned with flowers by another man"?

Tags: pali-canon, five-precepts

In the [Cunda Kammaraputta Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an10/an10.176.than.html) (translated by Thanissaro Bhikkhu):

> He engages in sensual misconduct. He gets sexually involved with those
>   who are protected by their mothers, their fathers, their brothers,
>   their sisters, their relatives, or their Dhamma; **those with
>   husbands**, those who entail punishments, or even **those crowned with
>   flowers by another man**.

Questions:

1. What is meant by "those crowned with flowers by another man"? Since this is differentiated from "those with husbands", can I guess that "those crowned with flowers by another man" refer to a woman who is not-yet-married but with a lover or fiancé who is committed to her?
2. If this assumption is correct, then can I take it that it is not a sexual misconduct for an unmarried adult woman, who is not protected by her parents or relatives, to become sexually involved with with a lover or fiancé who is committed to her?
3. Also, what is meant by "those who entail punishments"?

Comment: I think these questions are [answered here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/1371/254) by Ven. Yuttadhammo's "rough translation" of the commentary.